# An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host - caused by a connection timeout?

Tags: asp.net, connection

UPDATED:
An oldish ASP.net site with 3 forms is randomly creating the error: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host when these forms are sumitted

- The clients and their networks causing the error are seemingly random
- The httperr logs have Timer_ConnectionIdle log entries associated to some of the same IPs that are generating the aforementioned error.

  TARGETSITE: Int32 Receive(Byte[], Int32, Int32, System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags)

  Stack Trace:

  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
     at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)`

Could increasing the Connection Timeout setting in IIS resolve this issue?

Any ideas? Could an idle connection eventually cause this error?

Comment: When I've experienced this in the past, many times it was due to hardware issues on the server. I one particular case it was a matter of the NIC driver in the server being buggy. But if it's only happening on one form, I'd definitely start with the Application Pool associated with the site that has the form. Increase your script and application timeouts and see if that helps. Do you have a lot of other forms and this one is the only one with the issue?

Comment: This is the only form, and it's a long one (not very user friendly). The rest of the application is a .net CMS. Ive increased the timeouts ... fingers crossed.